# Matlab Octave Access Struct array member without loop

Tags: matlab, struct, octave

I hope this question is not too embarrassing, but i didn't find a solution via google (Most likely because i don't know the matching keywords):

If i have a struct array in Matlab with an entry `.data`, is there a loop less solution to search in this entries for eg. the maximum value?

```
num = 10;
block = struct('header',cell(num,1), 'data',cell(num,1));
% Some data in block; Perhaps this can be achieved without the loop as well?
for i = 1:num
  block(i).data = rand(1, 1);
end
% How do i get the corresponding max value of all block.data entries?
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Concatenate the result of `block.data` horizontally or vertically and then use [`max`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/max.html).

```
max([block.data])
```